# Adobe CQ5 : While setting up dispatcher, which URL in the ‘Transport’ tab, we have to set... Please explain in brief

Tags: aem

In the dispatcher flush in publish agent, which URL we have to set in transport tab. 
On different web pages, I came across, it is mentioned as

In the ‘Transport’ tab, set the “URI” as /dispatcher/invalidate.cache  Eg. http://dispatcherwebserver.company.com:80/dispatcher/invalidate.cache

Is this correct, after setting this URL, I am not able to check whether it is a correct URL or not. Please help.

Comment: You say you're not able to check if you have the correct URL, which suggests you've tried and failed (a good step before asking a question here); please share what you've tried and what happened in detail.

Comment: @acrosman   After adding, the       http://localhost/dispatcher/invalidate.cache                                            the following line appears in dispatcher-flush in publish agent. Replicating to http://localhost/dispatcher/invalidate.cache    But when I am clicking Test Connection, nothing is happening. Please note I have enabled the dispatcher flush ....

Comment: @YogeshRustagi What do you mean that 'nothing happens'? — The browser is a completely white page? The test is marked as failed? What is output to the logs?

Answer (score 2):

The dispatcher flush agent waits until some resource is activated. If it happens the agent will send a HTTP request to the dispatcher URL defined in the *Transport* tab. Request will contain HTTP headers telling the dispatcher which path should be invalidated.

Therefore, if you want it to work correctly, you need to provide an URL where you had configured the dispatcher:

1. if you don't have virtualhosts and the dispatcher runs on the same server as the publish instance, then the `http://localhost/dispatcher/invalidate.cache` should work.
2. if you don't have virtualhosts but the dispatcher and publish runs on different servers, use the IP address of the dispatcher server, like `http://192.168.10.10/dispatcher/invalidate.cache`
3. if you do have virtualhosts, use the virtualhost name: `http://my.virtualhost.com/dispatcher/invalidate.cache`

If your Apache httpd server runs on different port than **80**, add this port to the URL (eg. `http://localhost:8080/dispatcher/...`)

More information can be found in the [official Adobe manual](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/deploying/dispatcher/page_invalidate.html#Invalidating%20Dispatcher%20Cache%20from%20a%20Publishing%20Instance).